# Why is there a "<ssid>.b" alongside <ssid>?

Tags: wireless-router, dd-wrt

I just installed [dd-wrt on WRT54G 6.0](http://dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Linksys_WRT54G_v5.0_%26_5.1_%26_6.0) and noticed that it is broadcasting on both the SSID I assigned it (say, `myssid`) and one that has `.b` appended to it (`myssid.b`). I have since changed it so that the network mode to `G-Only` with no virtual interfaces set up, but `myssid.b` is still broadcasting, even after a power cycle.

When I connect to `myssid.b`, it has no internet access and I can't seem to access the router management page. However, I still have a slight concern that the router has an open network that isn't secured.

Why is dd-wrt broadcasting two SSIDs, and is there any way to disable it?

Comment: Did you check that the `.b` SSID is actually coming from the WRT54G (for instance by comparing the MAC addresses)? It's not unusual for headless WiFi-enabled devices (e.g. Chromecast) to use `.b` SSIDs for set-up purposes.

Comment: Ah that was it. Had to set up my Chromecast again and it switched me to that SSID to do so.

Answer (score 1):

The SSID.B broadcast should disappear after initial configuration has finalized and Chromecast has connected to the (secure) network.

It seems like chromecast broadcast a SSID.B if it looses connection to your routers secure SSID.

I noticed this SSID.B couple of times and finally got it connected to the fact that my router had a (short) connection timeout.
You can verify it by shutting down the router and monitor available networks.

When Chromecast reconnects to secure network again the SSID.B broadcast disappears.

As far as I figure out the only risk is your neighbor highjack your telly and configure your TV to only have channels with reruns available